# How to add two row of TableView depending on same id

Tags: swift, uitableview

First I am attaching an image of the scenario:

[image]

I wan to add the same subID and show them in a single row, adding their total as well. There should be any simple array append or map function, which I am unable to find. My **cellForRowAt indexPath:** looks like this:

```
   var walletTransactionModel = [WalletTransactionModel]()
   ...

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "walletCell", for: indexPath)
   let data = walletTransactionModel[indexPath.row - 1]
   let myNumber = doubleToIntWhenDecimalZero(number: data.amount)
   cell.textLabel?.text = "\(data.slug) | \(data.name) | \(myNumber)"
   return cell
```

And my simple model looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class WalletTransactionModel {
var slug: String
var name: String
var amount: Double

required init(slug: String, name: String, amount: Double) {
    self.slug = slug
    self.name = name
    self.amount = amount
}

convenience init?(item: JSON) {
    guard let slug = item["slug"].string,
           let name = item["name"].string,
        let amount = item["amount"].double else { return nil}

    self.init(slug: slug, name: name, amount: amount)
}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing to do is to get your data correct before you try to display it in the table view.  After you have loaded your data, run a processing step that reduces that data to the form you want.

**Something like this (copy paste to a playground):**

```swift
import Foundation

class WalletTransactionModel {
    var slug: String
    var name: String
    var amount: Double

    required init(slug: String, name: String, amount: Double) {
        self.slug = slug
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
    }
}

var data = [WalletTransactionModel(slug: "subID1", name: "James", amount: 1),
            WalletTransactionModel(slug: "subID1", name: "James", amount: 2),
            WalletTransactionModel(slug: "subID2", name: "Sarah", amount: 10),
            WalletTransactionModel(slug: "subID2", name: "Sarah", amount: 20)]


var reducedData = data.reduce( [WalletTransactionModel]()) { (partial, model) in
    var partial = partial

    let matchingIndex = partial.firstIndex(where: { (existingModel) -> Bool in
        existingModel.slug == model.slug
    })

    if let matchingIndex = matchingIndex {
        partial[matchingIndex].amount += model.amount
    } else {
        partial.append(model)
    }

    return partial
}

for model in reducedData {
    print("\(model.slug) \(model.amount)")
}
```

You can probably do this a bit more efficiently, but hopefully it's clear what's going on there.  Basically it reduces your existing data, and on each partial result checks to see if the id has already been added to the new result.  If it has then the amounts are summed, otherwise it adds the model to the new result.

This will process your data, and create a new data array.  You can then use this as your table view data source, and you won't need to do anything in `cellForRowAtIndex` other than display the row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dictionary's` **`init(grouping:by:)`** to group your `walletTransactionModel` elements by `slug`, i.e.

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: walletTransactionModel, by: { $0.slug })
```

Now, since `grouped` is a `Dictionary` of type `[String : [WalletTransactionModel]]`, we need to further get a single combined `WalletTransactionModel` from  `[WalletTransactionModel]` `array` obtained as `values` in the `grouped` `Dictionary`, i.e.

```
let arr = grouped.values.compactMap { (models) -> WalletTransactionModel? in
    if let name = models.first?.name, let slug = models.first?.slug {
        let amount = models.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.amount }
        let model = WalletTransactionModel(slug: slug, name: name, amount: amount)
        return model
    }
    return nil
}
```

`arr` is an `array` of type  `[WalletTransactionModel]` after combining the `WalletTransactionModel` instances based on `slug` and adding the respective `amount`.

**Example:**

If the `walletTransactionModel` is defined as,

```
let walletTransactionModel = [WalletTransactionModel(slug: "subID3", name: "Brian", amount: 10),
                              WalletTransactionModel(slug: "subID3", name: "Brian", amount: 12),
                              WalletTransactionModel(slug: "subID3", name: "Brian", amount: 15),
                              WalletTransactionModel(slug: "subID7", name: "Russel", amount: 10),
                              WalletTransactionModel(slug: "subID7", name: "Russel", amount: 11)]
```

Then `arr` will contain the following elements,

```
[WalletTransactionModel(slug: "subID3", name: "Brian", amount: 37.0), WalletTransactionModel(slug: "subID7", name: "Russel", amount: 21.0)]
```

Next, use `arr` as `dataSource` of the `tableView` to get the required UI.

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer but I am accepting the first answer as it was answered first. I could not decide which one to accept as both answer is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you needed a new array where you have to make new objects of the WalletTransactionModel according to your need.

```
if(walletTransactionModel.count>0){
//create an array for storing values
var resultArray = [WalletTransactionModel]()
//Iterate the keys, filter all items in walletTransactionModel with the same slug
//, sum up the values and create a new WalletTransactionModel with the total value:
let allKeys = Set<String>(walletTransactionModel.map{$0.slug})
for key in allKeys {
    let sum = walletTransactionModel.filter({$0.slug == key}).map({$0.amount}).reduce(0, +)
    let nameObj = walletTransactionModel.filter({$0.slug == key})[0].name
    resultArray.append(WalletTransactionModel(slug:key, name:nameObj , amount: sum))
}
//sort here if needed
resultArray.sorted(by: {$0.slug < $1.slug})
}
if (resultArray.count>0){
let data = resultArray[indexPath.row - 1]
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(data.slug) | \(data.name) | \(data.amount)"
}
else (cell.textLabel?.text = "empty")
```

thanks